# minimum date record

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, oracle10g

I need to get minimum date records for group by ColA,ColB,ColC. If date is same, then i need to get least Column E value. My table is huge table. i dont want use sub query or join. Any other way to get this using rank functions? please adivce.

```
ColA,ColB,ColC,ColD,ColE
abc,12,1,2015-01-01 00:00:01,1234
abc,12,1,2015-01-01 00:00:01,1235
abc,12,2,2015-01-01 00:00:01,1236
xyz,13,1,2015-01-02 00:00:01,1237
xyz,13,1,2015-01-03 00:00:01,1238
def,12,1,2015-01-01 00:00:01,1239
abc,12,1,2015-01-03 00:00:01,1230

Output:
ColA,ColB,ColC,ColD,ColE
abc,12,1,2015-01-01 00:00:01,1234
abc,12,2,2015-01-01 00:00:01,1236
xyz,13,1,2015-01-02 00:00:01,1237
def,12,1,2015-01-01 00:00:01,1239
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: which one are you using? sql-server or oracle?

Comment: Questions should include some code that shows you've at least attempted to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select ColA, ColB, ColC, min(ColD) as ColD,
       case when min(ColD) = max(ColD) then max(ColE) else min(ColE) end as ColE
from TableName
group by ColA, ColB, ColC
```

Comment: @Tom, tx, missed that.

Comment: This will output the incorrect values for `ColE`.  For example, the case of `abc, 12, 1`, it will choose the `ColD` of `2015-01-01 00:00:01` (correct) but the `ColE` of `1230` which is for the date `2015-01-03` -- the only possible values should be those which are both on `2015-01-01`, i.e., 1234 or 1235

Comment: I don't know, check the [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/1485).  That 1230 is coming from the last row of input, `abc,12,1,2015-01-03 00:00:01,**1230**` -- he is expecting that row to be `abc,12,1,2015-01-01 00:00:01,**1234**`

Comment: @Tom right, but OP has not mensioned what to pick if dates are different. He just said that he wants max if they are equal. So I assumed that other way it is not important

Comment: Gotcha, was just going off of his desired output that he put in the question.  This will not generate that